# NVD3.js highlight timestamps in times series

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to highlight some points in a time series modeled using a nvd3.js eventLineChart   - more precisely I have a json object with time-stamps and for each time-stamp I would like to add a vertical line at this particular date/time. The highlighted points may not exist in the time-series data source and are global over all groups of the time-series data (like ticks).

Any ideas on how this could be achieved? -  I tried adding a standard line to my plot (fixed y1 and y2 and x according to the timestamp of the events i want to highlight) but wasn't able to have the timestamps scaled to the same range as the original time series.

Here are some parts of the model I started to build for that purpose based on *nv.models.lineChart*. - (just an excerpt of the model as most of the code is just a copy from the lineChart model):

```
nv.models.eventLineChart = function() {
// adds vertical highlights to line chart
"use strict";

var chartEvents = {}

function chart(selection) {
    selection.each(function(data) {

        // Setup Scales
        x = lines.xScale();
        y = lines.yScale();

        // Setup containers and skeleton of chart
        var gEnter = wrap.enter().append('g').attr('class', 'nvd3 nv-wrap nv-lineChart').append('g');
        var g = wrap.select('g');
        gEnter.append('g').attr('class', 'nv-eventLinesWrap');
        //------------------------------------------------------------
        // Main Chart Component(s)
        var eventWrap = wrap
                            .select('.nv-eventLinesWrap')
                            .selectAll('.nv-eventLines')
                            .data(function(d) {return d });

        eventWrap
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'nv-eventLines');

        // chartEvents json ==> [{decsription: "test,"timestamp: 1375031820000}]
        var eventLine = eventWrap
                            .selectAll('.nv-eventLine')
                            .data(chartEvents, function(d){return (d.timestamp)});

        var eventLineEnter = eventLine.enter()
            .append('line').attr('class', 'nv-eventLine')
            .style('stroke-opacity', 0);

        // @todo set ymin and ymax
        eventLine
            .attr('x1', function(d){ return x(d.timestamp);})
            .attr('x2', function(d){ return x(d.timestamp);})
            .attr('y1', 300)
            .attr('y2', 800)
            .style('stroke', function(d,i,j) { return color(d,j) })
            .style('stroke-opacity', function(d,i) {
                return 1;
            });
    });
    return chart;
}

chart.setChartEvents = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return chartEvents;
    chartEvents = _;
    return chart;
};    
return chart;}
```

This model is called by using:

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
var nv3dChart = nv.models.eventLineChart().useInteractiveGuideline(true).setChartEvents(json.chartEvents);
// json.chartEvents >> [{decsription: "EventDescription,"timestamp: 1375031820000}]

nv3dChart.xAxis
    .showMaxMin(false);
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d")(new Date(d)) }); 

nv3dChart.yAxis
    .axisLabel(widgetConfig.action.data.kpiName)
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',.f'));

var ndg = d3.select(renderToElementId+' svg');
ndg.datum([{
        values: json.data,
        key: widgetConfig.action.data.tagName
    }])    
.transition().duration(500);

nv.utils.windowResize(nv3dChart.update);

return nv3dChart;})
```

Which produces currently this svg output (events that should be displayed by vertical lines only)

```
    <g class="nv-eventLines">
    <line class="nv-eventLine" x1="1375031820000" x2="1375031820000" y1="300" y2="800" style="stroke: #1f77b4;"></line>
</g>
```

.. as described I haven't yet figured out a way to implement the scaling of the events x values according to the scale of the line chart

Would greatly appreciate any help regarding this problem

Comment: You should be able to get the scale used for the chart by calling `chart.xScale()`.

Comment: Ok well you really have to show us the code then :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt reply ... i tried experimenting with chart.xScale already but didnt succeed - i created a nvd3 module for this purpose and set the lines with 
`   
var eventLine = eventWrap.selectAll('.nv-eventLine').data(chartEvents, function(d){return (d.timestamp)});
var eventLineEnter = eventLine.enter()
.append('line').attr('class', 'nv-eventLine')            
eventLine
                    .attr('x1', function(d){ return d.timestamp;})
                    .attr('x2', function(d){ return d.timestamp;})
`
maybe i have a conceptional problem

Comment: You need to access the original scale used for the x axis. How to do that exactly depends on what NVD3 module you based your code on.

Comment: im using just a copy of the basic line chart (nv.models.lineChart) whereas scales are set with x=lines.xScale()

Comment: So in what way did the x scale you got not work for you?

Comment: i didnt manage to make the scale actually scale my values (i tried passing the x value (in unix ms) to x() but it returned the same value again .. so the x values for the vertical line are set to the milliseconds and not to the scaled values

Comment: Could you show us a complete example?

Comment: yes of course, but i will extract just the parts I've edited as the complete model has about 600+ lines and is just a copy of base lineChart

Comment: You don't seem to be setting the domain or range of the x scale. You need to use the one that is used in drawing the lines, not a different one.

Comment: Yep, that is correct. - But the thing is that the var _lines_ refer to the time series data and is initialized with nv.models.line(). - This function again builds upon nv.models.scatter() where the scales are actually set up (based on optional configurations and - if not further specified - on the data itself; therefore the time series in my case) ... i now would like to use the scale that is automatically set in the scatter function to scale my "events" .. and this is for whatever reason not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now manually created all scales for x and y and added them to the nvd3 elements. I'm not particularly happy with that solution as it prevents me from creating a more modular feature for multiple nvd3 charts but it is a starting point.

Here is an outline of my current solution:

```
nv.models.eventLineChart = function() {
// initialize scales
var y = d3.scale.linear(),
    x = d3.scale.linear();

// set scales of lines
lines = nv.models.line()
        .yScale(y)     


function chart(selection) {
    //@todo support for multiple series 

    // set domain and range for scales
    x
    .domain(d3.extent(data[0].values, function(d){return d.x}))
    .range([0,availableWidth]);

    y
    .domain(d3.extent(data[0].values, function(d){return d.y}))
    .range([0,availableHeight]);

    // add container for vertical lines
    gEnter.append('g').attr('class', 'nv-eventLinesWrap');

    // setup container
    var eventWrap = wrap.select('.nv-eventLinesWrap').selectAll('.nv-eventLines')
        .data(function(d) {return d });

    eventWrap.enter().append('g').attr('class', 'nv-eventLines');
    eventWrap.select('.nv-eventLinesWrap').attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (-margin.top) +')');

    var eventLine = eventWrap.selectAll('.nv-eventLine').data(chartEvents, function(d){return (d.timestamp)});
    var eventLineEnter = eventLine.enter()
        .append('line').attr('class', 'nv-eventLine')

    // configure and style vertical lines
    //@todo: set color for lines 
    eventLine
        .attr('x1', function(d){ return x(d.timestamp)})
        .attr('x2', function(d){ return x(d.timestamp)})
        .attr('y1', y.range()[0])
        .attr('y2', y.range()[1])
        .style('stroke', function(d,i,j) { return "#000"; })
        .style('stroke-width',1)

    // @todo add vertical lines via transitions, add vLine content to toolbox
}}
```

Thank you, Lars, for your contributions .. they really helped a lot to understand certain parts in more detail.

If anyone has come up with a better idea to solve this problem I would be very grateful if you could post these suggestions here!

Comment: It's ok to accept your own answer. That way this will not be in the Unanswered page.